# Prevent VBA code from other workbook working with objects

Tags: vba

I need to disable a control (list box in this case), so user cannot get data from other departments. I do have a macro that can enable/disable it, and ask for password.

What I need is to prevent semidecent user to write a macro for enabling this list box in another workbook and unlocking it this way. It is possible in some way prevent VBA code from other modules to work with this control? So only code written in that one sheet can enable or disable it.

Thank you

Comment: Where is the listbox, on a sheet?

Comment: VBA code shouldn't run on the worksheet if the worksheet is locked with a password and `UserInterFaceOnly` isn't set to `true`.

Comment: Yes list box is visible on a sheet

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is lock your VBA project and change your "subs" into "function", this way, a more advanced user have no access to the macro you've written without unlocking the project.

(Functions are not visible from the "assign a macro" button in the developer ribbon where Subs are)

Answer (score 0):

I tried `UserInterFaceOnly` - and I'm not sure at this moment what it is supposed to do but it is not doing what I wanted

To be more clear, I have 2 list boxes and several comboboxes on Sheet1. When I'm sending file to users, I want to lock ListBoxes, or rather `.enabled = False`

What I'm trying to do is to prevent other user to write in some other workbook

```
 Workbooks("opexRequest").Sheets("Report").ListBoxes("lstDepartment").Enabled = True
```

this line woudl enable the list box, and user can change values, and macro will genarate new SQL string for Departments user is not supposed to have access to. I need to have comboboxes enabled, so user can view different dates, and versions of plan for his department.

By accident I found a way I guess.

Within Sheet1 I have this code

```
Sub lstDepartment_change()

        'checks first if lock checkbox is true/false, clears selection and disables listbox, _
        if checkbox is locked and yet listbox is enabled and allows change

        If Me.chkLock = True Then
                Me.ListBoxes("lstDepartment").Enabled = False
                Me.ListBoxes("lstdirector").Enabled = False
                Call clearlistbox
                End
            ElseIf Me.chkLock = False Then
                Call ControlsM.directorpopulation
        End If

    End Sub



    Sub lstDirector_change()

        'checks first if lock checkbox is true/false, clears selection and disables listbox, _
        if checkbox is locked and yet listbox is enabled and allows change

        If Me.chkLock = True Then
            Me.ListBoxes("lstDepartment").Enabled = False
            Me.ListBoxes("lstdirector").Enabled = False
            Call clearlistbox
            End
        ElseIf Me.chkLock = False Then

        End If


    End Sub



    Private Sub chkLock_Click()

        'locking/unlocking with password inbox call

        If Me.chkLock.Value = True Then
                Me.ListBoxes("lstDepartment").Enabled = False
                Me.ListBoxes("lstDirector").Enabled = False
            ElseIf Me.chkLock.Value = False Then

                If PasswordInputBoxM.InputBoxPassword("Enter password", "Password Required") = "****" Then
                        Me.ListBoxes("lstDepartment").Enabled = True
                        Me.ListBoxes("lstDirector").Enabled = True
                    Else
                        Me.chkLock.Value = True
                        MsgBox "Wrong Password"
                        Exit Sub
                End If
        End If

    End Sub
```

If someone tries to unlock just listbox, and tries to change value, it will check the checkbox value, and clears the selected list and locks the listbox
If someone tries to unlock listbox and uncheck lock checkbox, it will automatically ask for password
Problem is, that someone can change selected value from other workbook. I do not know how to handle that

```
 Workbooks("opexRequest").Sheets("Report").ListBoxes("lstDepartment").Enabled = True 'handled
    Workbooks("opexRequest").Sheets("Report").chkLock.value = False 'handled
    Workbooks("opexRequest").Sheets("Report").ListBoxes("lstDepartment").Selected(1) = True 'do not know how to prevent this
```

Comment: This should be an edit to your original question, rather than an answer to it.